# Do Soap, Wax, or Oil Have Any Special Effects on Magnetic Fields Around Them?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I'm curious if these materials affect magnetic fields. Came from a thought about wax used to reduce friction for skateboarding grinds.

Comment: I’m trying to see a connection between waxing snowboards and magnetic fields.

Comment: soaps, waxes and oils have negligible effects on magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Closest things, where oil and magnets somehow are working together are [oil + nano particles of iron oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrofluid) that is attracted to magnet, especially if it is also [rheoscopic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cmuy6evscuc), [oil volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_rotator) that is under magnetic field and can change light polarization,

1 and 2 rely on particles in liquid. 3 relies on interaction with light. Nothing of oil and magnetic fields reacting directly.

With electric fields there is [electrospray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tv6eGTfsFzU) where oil can be accelerated using the electric field, so can air. Keep in mind that this youtuber has questionable safety procedures.

Comment: That video of the electrospray is very cool. He could tone the volume down on the lightning cracks huh?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not simple Yes/No question.

Actually, there is inherent diamagnetism in every material, which can be derived using quantum mechanics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism

Therefore, strictly speaking, every material interacts to the magnetic field.  Of course, when we call "Magnetic material", we usually refer paramagnet, ferromagnet, ferrimagnet, etc.

Although the materials you mentioned have no such "Magnetic" properties, they have at least quantum mechanical diamagnetism. On the other hand, when the soap is dissolved in water, the ions in soap has electric charge, and will show diamagnetism which can be explained through plasma physics.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's interesting about the soap's ions being charged when it's dissolved in water. So soapy water shows diamagnetism? Then wouldn't soap in bar or liquid form do that also?

Comment: @MichaelWegter That diamagnetism requires that those ions in the soap move freely. Thus, if not in any liquid, that diamagnetism will not occur.